# Can the sum of different sets Fibonacci numbers be the same?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Is it possible to have two sets having at least one different element and the sum of Fibonacci of all elements be the same?

As in, two subsets:

```
A = {x,y,z,w,a}
B = {d,e,b,c}
```

is it possible to have:

```
fib(x)+fib(y)+fib(z)+fib(w)+fib(a) = fib(d)+fib(e)+fib(b)+fib(c)
```

Comment: Yes, because $F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$, so you can pick $A=\{n\}$ and $B=\{n-1,n-2\}$.

Comment: Every positive integer can be written uniquely as a sum of **non-consecutive** Fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is. Look at the definition af the Fibonacci numbers:
$$F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$$
Both the LHS and the RHS are a subset of the Fibonacci numbers